# Find appropriate number fill in the blanks

Tags: puzzle

Find appropriate number fill in the blanks [image]

Comment: Can you at least provide *some* context?

Comment: With no more effort to explain what you want than what you have provided, why should a well-meaning stranger rake himself over the coals to help you?

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi That seemed a little extreme, but alright.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option:

- Take the only number that appears twice in the small circles of a diagram
- Add that pair of numbers, subtract one from the result, and put it in the big circle

a) $3+3-1=5$

b) $18+18-1=35$

c) $43+43-1=85$

Comment: (+1) For the *one option* remark and possible explanation. Questions like this bug me...I mean all sorts of answers are possible, but kudos. :-)

Comment: @crash: I agree. There's hardly any real math involved here. It's just a "show that you can find the pattern" kind of question.

Comment: @Rain: What?????

Comment: @Rain That **one** comment you just made...that should be a question in and of itself: someone decipher this gibberish...